# How to support password protection to a document similar to keynote in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, icloud

Is there any apple API to support encryption of a document similar to keynote application(.key file) or in general how to support encryption to entire document.

I can't encrypt entire folder because in iCloud scenario small change will trigger the entire document to upload looks like i am missing something.

I just tried to see how the files are encrypted in keynote. In the below image left side is document without password and other one is with password.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. What makes you think the files are encrypted? How did you obtain the these files?

Comment: It is the exported file from keynote via mail with password and without password.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no straight forward way to encrypt entire document we have to do file by file.